# Date to Integer conversion in Java

Tags: java, date

I have an int variable with following. How can I convert it to Date object and vice versa.

```
int inputDate=20121220;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Convert the value to a `String` and use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse it to a `Date` object:

```
int inputDate = 20121220;
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date date = df.parse(String.valueOf(inputDate));
```

The converse is similar, but instead of using [`parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29), use [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29), and convert from the resulting `String` to an `Integer`:

```
String s = date.format(date);
int output = Integer.valueOf(s);
```

An alternative is to use `substring` and manually parse the `String` representation of your `Int`eger, though I **strongly advise you against** this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String input = String.valueOf(inputDate);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.valueOf(input.substring(0, 4)));
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.valueOf(input.substring(4, 6)) - 1);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.valueOf(input.substring(6)));
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Can we do without using parse method?

Comment: @VinayKumarChella: Yes, check my update. Although I suggest, if you can, to use `SimpleDateFormat` instead. It's much more flexible.